# How to open a modal on button click in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have tried below code its working fine for first time, but when I close popup and click on button again it stops working.

```
 var myForm = new Ext.form.Panel({
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        title: 'Foo',
        floating: true,
        closable : true
    });
    //myForm.show();

Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click Me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
           myForm.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default [closeAction](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#cfg-closeAction) is equal to 'destroy', which means component will be destroyed on clicking the close button. After you destroy your `myForm` object, it won't be available on the second try.

solution:
1) You can change `closeAction` to 'hide' and after clicking the close button component will just hide in dom.

```
var myForm = new Ext.form.Panel({
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Foo',
    floating: true,
    closable: true,
    closeAction: 'hide'//<-------------
});
```

2) You can create new object on every click on the button.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click Me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        click: function () {
            new Ext.form.Panel({
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                title: 'Foo',
                floating: true,
                closable: true
            }).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your panel. That would hide it after you close it

```
            closeAction: 'hide'
```

If you were building a big screen though you'd be better off leaving it as is (it keeps the dom tidy) but you'll need to recreate the component then when you click the button again